# Can I charge for public transportation?

Tags: simcity-2013

My city predictably is having money shortages. I am barely breaking even and have already taken three bonds. Suddenly I remember that I have a very nice public transportation (shuttle bus) system that, maybe, I can monetize. Is there any way that I can set a fare for my buses (or any other public transportation systems) and recoup some of the expenses?

Comment: I would try Ministry of Public Transportation (only one city in a region needs any particular ministry to unlock stuff for all cities). If that doesn’t work, then SC works at the proper model — subsidise PT, because it saves money on traffic delays, fuel consumption, road wear and pollution.

Comment: As for money, I only needed PT when I hit 5000. By that time, I borrowed and paid off four bonds, and now make decent amount with healthy cash flow.

Comment: I too have come up to making decent money again. But it would still be nice to know if this is possible.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to adjust the fares charged by public transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to charge for public transport in SimCity. The purpose of mass transit in SimCity is to provide a method to control the traffic and air pollution in your city.

Comment: Unfortunately you are probably right. It is ironic then that the municipal buses from neighboring cities can cause as much traffic as they alleviate.

Comment: Are there any fares at all for public transportation?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals It doesn't seem so.

Answer (score -1):

With the current state of the game there are no tollbooths or anything of that manner like there were in SimCity 4. But I am sure in the future whether it is through community mods or DLC there will be such content.